# Not able to submit forms with a large number of input fields, after moving to wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

After moving to wildfly 10 from an old version of jboss, we can no longer submit large forms. If a form contains about 900 input fields or more, a blank page is returned after submitting the form. Nothing is added to the server log after submitting the form.

I Have tried to add max-post-size and max-header-size to the http-listener but without any luck:

```
<http-listener name="default" max-post-size="10485760" max-header-size="974247881" socket-binding="http" url-charset="ISO-8859-1" redirect-socket="https"/>
```

Do any of you have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable `max-parameters` in undertow subsystem

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" max-parameters="NUMBER_YOU_wANT"/>
```